# SQL - Check which record came first

Tags: sql, compare, subquery

Sorry if this is simple but somehow I'm banging my head on my desk because I've always had trouble with nested queries.

Basic query: Select FILENO, CODE, RECNO FROM DOCUMENT WHERE CODE = 'CODE1' results in the following table.

```
FILENO    CODE    RECNO
FILE1     CODE1   13494
FILE2     CODE1   13499
FILE3     CODE1   13597
```

Second query: Select FILENO, CODE, RECNO FROM DOCUMENT WHERE CODE = 'CODE2' results in the following table.

```
FILENO    CODE    RECNO
FILE1     CODE2   13495
FILE2     CODE2   13498
FILE3     CODE2   13600
```

What I need is to check to see if CODE2 was entered before CODE1.  The result could be the first table with a RESULT column with Y or N in it.

Comment: What about equality?  what if RecNo is the same for the same file? Y/N or what?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would use a nested query here.  A join seems like it would work.. though you didn't say what should happen if the two are equal.

Now if there there is now if either code1 or code2 doesn't exist, then no records will be returned.  we could use an outer join if needed...

```
SELECT A.FileNo
     , A.Code
     , A.RecNo
     , CASE when A.RecNo > B.RecNo then 'Y' 
            when A.RecNo < B.RecNo then 'N' 
            else 'Undef' End as isCode1Newer
FROM Document A
INNER JOIN Document B
  on A.FileNo = B.FileNo
WHERE A.Code = 'CODE1'
  and B.Code = 'CODE2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate per code to check this, so as to have to read the table just once:

```
select
  code,
  case when
    max(case when code = 'CODE1' then recno end) >
    max(case when code = 'CODE2' then recno end) then 'Y' else 'N'
  end as c2_before_c1
from mytable
where code in ('CODE1', 'CODE2')
group by code;
```